# How to create Right Click and Middle Click event on custom hyperlink button?

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am creating my Custom hyperlink button deriving from Silverlight HyperlinkButton I want to create Right Click and Middle click event on it. Can some help me please.

Thanks,
Gobind

Answer (score 0):

I would add a couple of events (like `MiddleClick` and `RightClick`), then handle the `MouseUp` (or `MouseDown`, if you want to intercept on the down), then fire one of the two events depending on the details of the MouseUp event.  For example:

```
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MouseUp += OnMouseUp;
}

void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Middle)
    {
        OnMiddleClick(e);
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
        OnRightClick(e);
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}

public event MouseButtonEventHandler RightClick;

protected virtual void OnRightClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = RightClick;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}

public event MouseButtonEventHandler MiddleClick;

protected virtual void OnMiddleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = MiddleClick;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply Peter. I am using the Silverlight hyperlink button and MouseUp event doesn't exist in Silverlight. I can create RightClick on MouseRightButtonUp but I need to create the MiddleClick using JavaScript, as much i read over web, there is no way to listen middle click using xaml/C#. So can I get some idea how can I listen to mouse MiddleClick using the JS??